# How can I use validation rules set in a model in several controllers in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.1

For the sign-up form for my website I don't require that users confirm their passwords so there isn't a password confirmation field.

However when a user resets their password and they click the link in their email and then taken to a change password page I require they confirm their password and provide a field for them to do this.

My question is how can I add password confirmation and min and max lengths for passwords with out it affecting my sign up form because they use they same model. For my signup form I have min and max length validation rules and want these to apply to the change password form but also include password confirmation.

What is the best and most convenient way to do this in your opinion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If password confirmation should only be done for users already created, the simplest solution is :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates_confirmation_of :password, :unless => :new_record?
end
```

So it will only call the validation when setting the value for new users and not for users trying to sign up.

Comment: No luck, I've added this to my user model and added the password_confirmation field to my view file for the change password form and it detects if I leave the first password field blank but if I fill that in and click submit it still submits without confirmation

Comment: Ok I forgot to add :password_confirmation to attr_accessible. I still wouldn't be able to explain what attr_accessible does if someone asked me. I know that attr_accessor creates setter and getter methods. Useful for attributes that don't exist in the database.. such as my password attribute because my passwords are encrypted and stored in a separate attritibute. This is the reason why I thought I would get the password confirmation validation working by adding password_confirmation to the attr_accessor list but it happended to work when I added it to the attr_accessible.. Slightly confused

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own methods to validate model data, something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :user_data_validation

  def user_data_validation

    errors.add(:password_confirmation, "error in the password confirmation") if
      !password.blank? and password != password_confirm
  end
end
```

On the other hand you can use control-level validations, but:

> Controller-level validations can be tempting to use, but often become
>   unwieldy and difficult to test and maintain. Whenever possible, it’s a
>   good idea to keep your controllers skinny, as it will make your
>   application a pleasure to work with in the long run. [(c)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html)